# How do you get a list or dict of user-defined properties in a Kivy Widget instance?

Tags: python-3.x, properties, kivy

I want to create a method that can directly access the user-defined properties of a Kivy Widget Class as a list or dict. (In order to pass them in as an argument into another instance of the same class).

python file:

```
from kivy.uix.behavior import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class ExampleWidget(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    name = StringProperty()
    hometown = StringProperty()
    school = StringProperty()

    def clone_self(self):
        # Psuedo-Code
        args = [v for v in self.user_defined_properties]
        clone = ExampleWidget(*args)
        return clone
```

I have tried a number of things, such as dir, var and **dict** as well using the .get() value as [defined in the kivy properties docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html) all to no avail.

My current set up has two methods, one that returns a manually defined dict of properties, the other which creates and returns the clone using the first method.

Using this, my code is functional however I'm quite sure that a lot of it is unnecessary due to some built in method I'm not entirely sure how to access.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your properties on class level. See this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, Property

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'Print properties'
        on_press: root.print_properties()
''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    name = StringProperty()
    hometown = StringProperty()
    school = StringProperty()
    num = NumericProperty()

    def print_properties(self):
        for k, v in vars(self.__class__).items():
            if isinstance(v, Property):
                print(k)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Compare it with

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, Property

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'Print properties'
        on_press: root.print_properties()
''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(*args)

        self.name = StringProperty()
        self.hometown = StringProperty()
        self.school = StringProperty()
        self.num = NumericProperty()

    def print_properties(self):
        for k, v in vars(self).items():
            if isinstance(v, Property):
                print(k)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

---

EDIT: As I've just discovered, there's also [properties()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=properties#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.properties) method that should be used instead of `vars()`:

```
for k, v in self.properties().items():
    print(type(v))
```

Comment: This has helped clear up somethings but I'm still confused somewhat. [Something like this](https://pastebin.com/8njeDkSS) however I'm now getting errors about name only accepts string. I think this is because I'm trying to pass in the Property itself rather than the value thereof?

Comment: Yep, something about that. If you use `kwargs[k] = v.get(self)` instead it should work. Btw, I updated the answer since I discovered that there's actually `properties()` method that returns them all.

Comment: So I've implemented the kwargs[k] = v.get(self), However when passing it into the creation, I run into 'AttributeError: Property is read-only'. I tried setting all of my properties to readonly=false but that wasn't the issue. Also tried disabling it before adding it to the dict but wasn't sure what to do there either.

Comment: Okay, so I tried both the example code used above, which works, but the error comes up when I try to use it in my actual project. [Error](https://pastebin.com/naKpfXMa) at first I thought it meant be a conflict because I was using the @property decorator on one of the methods (since the property here is lowercase p). This is what I have implemented in the [actual code](https://pastebin.com/1Y3AnzuZ) and the same thing in the [example code](https://pastebin.com/wyYZPejj).

Comment: Okay so I went back and tried something [similar to your first code](https://pastebin.com/b1gH1dEU) and it works perfectly! This doesn't seem to work with self.properties().items() because it is trying to get too many things (maybe because of the composite inheritance of this widget?)